# yaml property value

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

I am using yaml file to store attribute and value. But some of the values need the current date to be appended.

So how do I enter the value in yaml file, so that yaml parser can automatically recognise and substitute with current date

I am using pyyaml and python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyyaml does not automatically substitute anything. Just use a custom string e.g. `${now}` and replace it with the current date after parsing the yaml file.

For example,

```
value.replace("${now}", datetime.date.today().isoformat())
```

where `value` is a sting read from the input file.